# Novice GitHub question. No ssh problem; how to push a file?

Tags: github, push

Good morning,
after 4 useless hours of tutorial on the Net, I'm asking my question here.

1. I've created my SSH key and added it to Github
2. Then I've created a Repository called "Repo" on GitHub.com
3. Then I've created a folder called "Repo" on my computer and I've initialized git as usual : git.init etc...
4. But then if I want to push something, let's say the README.md, after :

```
git add README.md
git commit README.md
```

`git status` returns `"On the main branch Your branch is in advance of 3 commits upon 'origin/main' (Use "git push" to publish these local commits) Nothing to valid, the copy of your work is clean"`

But when I write :

```
git push README.md
```

I get

```
"Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists"
```

So, what's the explanation ?
`ssh -T git@github.com` returns : "Hi Aurelien! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." So I don't understand at all the problem.

EDIT : `git remote -v`  returns :

```
origin  git@github.com:Aurelien/Repo.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Aurelien/Repo.git (push)
```

Comment: Dear matt, what a cruel answer but I take it as I need help. I modify my message to quote the entire text, i.e. : "```git status``` returns ```"On the main branch Your branch is in advance of 3 commits upon 'origin/main' (Use "git push" to publish these local commits) Nothing to valid, the copy of your work is clean"```.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `git remote -v` as a code block?

Comment: Hi bk2204. I added the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is that you're writing `git push README.md`.  `git push` takes a remote name or URL, so what you're asking Git to do is to push to the local repository called `README.md`.  However, since that's a file, not a Git repository, it doesn't work.

When you want to push, write `git push origin`, or, assuming the branch you want to push is called `main`, `git push origin main`.  Note that this will push the entire history of your branch, not just the one file.  Git doesn't provide a way to push just one file; instead, it pushes a commit and the history leading up to it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. I'm going to rename this topic "Novice GitHub question". I was losing time on SSH while it wasn't a SSH problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's very unlikely that you're the only person to do this, so hopefully because you asked the question, someone else will benefit as well.